# Jquery array count up and down if element changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of a dom element if another function changes its fontsize.

example: 
**html:**

```
<p id="hi">
    VALUE
</p>
```

**jquery:**

```
fancyColors = {
  1: "blue",
  2: "green",
  3: "yellow",
  6: "#97bf0d"
};

$(function () {
    $("#hi").on("change", function () {
        var valuE = $('#hi');
        valuE.css("color", fancyColors[1]);
        var getSize = $('#hi').css("font-size");
        if (getSize != 16) {
            valuE.fancyColors[1++]
        } else {
            valuE.fancyColors[2--];
        }
    });
});
```

The default fontsize should be 16. Now if anything doesn't matter what or who changes it to less than 16. It should count up in the color array.

If it gets lower in font-size it should count down in array.

How do I do that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: dont understand the Question . you mean if less than 16 => count up, If font size is lower => do count down .But see font size less than 16 is lower so ,Should it be count UP,or count Down?

Comment: Are you sayingif font is greater than 16 it should increment the index and if less than 16 then it should decrement?

Comment: Do you think `1++` and `2--` is working?

Comment: Nope it's just for understanding purpose. I could have done a comment // count up in Array should I change it?

Comment: `change` is a completely different event, than what you think it is - you can use it when the contents of an input changes, for example, not when the fontSize of an element does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
fancyColors = {
  0: "blue",
  1: "green",
  2: "yellow",
  3: "#97bf0d"
};

$(function () {
     var i=0;
    $("#hi").on("change", function () {
        var valuE = $(this); // use $(this);
        if(i==4){// reinit i to 0
           i=0;
        }
        if(i<0){
           i=3;// set max limit
        }
        valuE.css("color", fancyColors[i]);
        var getSize = valuE.css("font-size");
        if (parseInt(getSize,10) != 16) { // parseInt to remove px from font-size
            i++; // use i++, and fancyColors is not an object of valuE
        } else {
            i--; // use i--
        }
    });
});
```

You can't use `valuE.fancyColors` as `fancyColors` is not an object of `valuE`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/A4PmL/)

**Updated** if you want to `trigger change event automatically` then try [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMSubtreeModified) like,

```
$("#hi").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/A4PmL/1/)

Comment: it says: TypeError: valuE.fancyColors is undefined
 

valuE.fancyColors[i++]; // use i++

Comment: If i replace it with "click" it works. if i change it to change it does nothing.

Comment: When your value is changing?

Comment: The event does't trigger if it's a "change" event. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I don't want to change it with a click event, I want it to change its color if something else triggers another function. Let's say there is another function with an click event. Then this example should only listen if it changes anything and should react on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use click method instead of change method. And there is syntax error like 1++. You cannot increase like this but do i++ by using for loop:

```
    fancyColors = {
          1: "blue",
          2: "green",
          3: "yellow",
          6: "#97bf0d"
        };

        $(function () {
          $("#hi").on("click", function() {

if(!this.defaultValue){
          var valuE = $('#hi');
       for(var i=0;i<fancyColors.length;i++){
          valuE.css("color", fancyColors[i]);
          var getSize = $('#hi').css("font-size");
        if(getSize != 16 ) {
          valuE.fancyColors[i++] 
        } else {
          valuE.fancyColors[i--]; 
        }
    }
}
        });
        });
```

---

change is used only for input element types.

Comment: But it shouldn't be activated on an click event. It should be active if anything changes.. is there a better function or method?

Comment: like $('#hi').text(valueE);